# cannot find symbol symbol: (maven and POM)

Tags: java, maven

I finally fix nearly all that was wrong in my POM for maven compilation but there is still one wrong dependency (?) 
In my servlet class a have got 5 errors typeof

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getDispatcherType()
  location: variable request of type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FORWARD
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable REQUEST
```

I have added in POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

because getDispatcherType is from package javax.servlet; 
but it still couldn't find this methods, perhaps someone could tell me what is wrong in this POM description?

PS  : org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:1.2.1  is also present

Comment: try to add the jstl-impl dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong dependency for jstl. You should be using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Your jsp dependency is correct.

Comment: I have just tried it - but the errors are the same(( anyway thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

finally after a hours of screwing around that piece of code I have found what exactly caused such trouble - the dependency of tomcat-servlet-api MUST BE FIRST in  section.
I am using 7.0.50 version by the way.

Comment: No, this isn't the problem. You are mistaken. If this works, then you have problems with multiple versions of the same class on the classpath. Use mvn dependency-tree and look for libraries with similar names and different versions or group-id's.

Answer (score 0):

I am using InteliJ IDEA, I highlighted at the point where I am importing the packages `import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;` and the IDE gave me an option of downloading  Java version 6 (Java EE 6) dependencies. That fixed the problem for me

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

update the version if you like to do so

Comment: Didn't i say to change the version ?